# If I date Liara in ME1, what will affect me if I want to date Tali in ME2 and 3?

Tags: mass-effect-series

Well, everythings's in the title.

I was wanting to date Tali (I just love the character) and I'm doing all the Mass Effect games. I'm currently Male Sheppard and in the original Mass Effect.

Tali isn't available in ME1, so I guess I'll date Liara instead.

I know about the picture in ME2, but is there any other effect? Knowing that I will keep Tali as my date in ME3?

Am I better not dating anyone since I don't care much about trophies?

Comment: [Related](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/125542/can-i-cheat-on-my-me1-sweetheart-in-me2-and-keep-our-romance-going-in-me3), but doesn't look like a dupe.

Comment: @MBraedley: Only related, he ask to get his ME1 date back in ME3 after cheating in ME2. I ask about the effect of keeping the ME2's date in ME3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can choose not to romance anyone. That keeps things super-simple.

If, however, you'd like your Shep to get some play, you can totally romance Liara in 1 and then Tali in 2 and 3. Liara might be a little sad about it, but she's not going to hate you or anything as a result. I'm not sure if Tali says anything about Liara in 2, since I've never gone down that road, but given how other romances go about it I'd say Tali will ask you about Liara, and you are given the option of backing out or saying "nope, it's all you".

Basically, you won't be penalized if you start with Liara in 1 and go with Tali in 2 and 3. Liara's not going to be a pain and keep info from you or whatever over it. At most, there might be a snarky comment or two, but that'd be about it.